# How to disable java script in Chrome Driver Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I disable Java Script in Selenium's Chrome Driver using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really difficult. You can try doing this way:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-javascript"));
```

But as it is written [here](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/08/disable-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver/), you can´t disable JavaScript if you use ChromeDriver2.

Comment: This did not work for me in Java. But I managed to do it with `ChromeDriver 2.41.578706` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57316009/1545579

Answer (score 28):

It's Really easy ! Just try this code !

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

If you want to disable Images, just replace javascript with image.

Comment: It works!! Thanks. i've made some tests with headless mode of Chrome, but in this case it doesn't seems to bem available.

Answer (score 7):

Disabling `JavaScript` in `Chrome` is possible with old `ChromeDriver` prior to `ChromeDriver2`, which only supports **Chrome 28 or under**. try as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

> **WARNING**: Running without `JavaScript` is unsupported and will likely break a large portion of the `ChromeDriver's` functionality. I
>   suspect you will be able to do little more than navigate to a page.
>   This is **NOT** a supported use case, and we will not be supporting
>   it.

Hope it will help you...:)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/), the configuration you have to use is

```
var CHROME_CONFIGURATION = {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    "chromeOptions" : {
        "prefs" : {
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2
        }
    }
};
```